# textView gets cut-off while using custom malayalam ttf font

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

My text view inside a list view gets cut off while using custom malayalam ttf font. I get the content for my list view through a rss feed http://www.techlokam.in/feed and my custom font is Meera_04-2.ttf
See the screenshot here http://imageshack.com/a/img208/8039/k7pp.png

How to fix this problem????

Following are my layout files

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#bababa"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" 
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>   
   </RelativeLayout>
```

rss item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dip" >


<!-- Article title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="1dip"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#303030"
    android:singleLine="false"
     />

<!-- published date -->
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/pub_date"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#b70400"/>

<!-- article description -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#8d8d8d"
    android:layout_below="@id/pub_date"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```